# EC2 No Region instances in Billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Does anyone know what it means to have billing for EC2 instances that are labeled No Region?

```
Elastic Compute Cloud
-$8,888.50
No Region
No Instance Type
```

Comment: Look in AWS cost explorer, it should have more detail.

Comment: Given that's a negative number is that a savings plan/reserved instance or something? As @Tim says cost explorer should explain it.

Answer (score 0):

**Refund**

Any refunds that you received. Refunds are listed as a separate line item in the data table. They don't appear as an item in the chart because they represent a ***negative value*** in the calculation of your costs. The chart displays only positive values.

Filtering the data that you want to view - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/latest/userguide/ce-filtering.html